# Cant delete a route from Scapy's route table?

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I tried deleting a route from a Scapy routing table with no success.
This is my table:

```
    Network      Netmask          Gateway      Iface   Output IP  Metric
0.0.0.0      0.0.0.0          192.168.3.1  enp0s8  10.0.0.1   20100 
10.0.0.0     255.255.255.0    0.0.0.0      enp0s8  10.0.0.1   100   
127.0.0.0    255.0.0.0        0.0.0.0      lo      127.0.0.1  1     
169.254.0.0  255.255.0.0      0.0.0.0      enp0s8  10.0.0.1   1000  
192.168.3.1  255.255.255.255  0.0.0.0      enp0s8  10.0.0.1   20100
```

I tried this command:

```
conf.route.delt(net="192.168.3.1/32",gw="0.0.0.0")
```

and got this error:

```
ValueError("No matching route found!")
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2):

When I run code like yours then in full error message I can see

```
ValueError: (3232236289, 4294967295, '0.0.0.0', 'enp0s8', '10.0.0.1', 1) is not in list
```

So I start checking [source code](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/route.py#L100) and I found that I can use

```
conf.route.routes
```

to see route table in different format - as list of tuples

```
[(2130706432, 4278190080, '0.0.0.0', 'lo', '127.0.0.1', 1),
 # ... other tuples ...
 (3232236289, 4294967295, '0.0.0.0', 'enp0s8', '10.0.0.1', 20100)]
```

When I compared it with value from error message then I saw they have different values for `metric` (last value in tuple). Table has `20100` but error shows `1`.

Code works for me if I add `metric` in `delt`

```
conf.route.delt(net="192.168.3.1/32", gw="0.0.0.0", metric=20100)
```

---

**EDIT:**

This allow also to delete route using index - i.e. to delete last item in table

```
del(conf.route.routes[-1])
```